# How to update the value in a VC when a tab is selected from a UITabbarController?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a tabbar controller. When the user clicks on one of the tab bar buttons, I need to update a value in the UIPageViewController that is in the target view controller.

I am trying to use a delegate to inform a UIPageViewController which tab bar button was clicked:

```
protocol PlanTypeDelegate {
    func setIntro(thisFlow planType: UITabBarItem)
}

class NewTabBarController: UITabBarController {

var planTypeDelegate : PlanTypeDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create and handle tab bar button actions
}


override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        planTypeDelegate?.setIntro(thisFlow: item)
    }
```

In my UIPageController I have the following:

```
class IntroPageController: UIPageViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

guard let tabbar = self.parent as? NewTabBarController() else { return }
    tabbar.delegate = self

}

}

extension IntroPageController : PlanTypeDelegate {
    func setIntro(thisFlow planType: UITabBarItem) {
        print("this item:\(planType)")
    }
}
```

Instead I get this error message:
[image]

I am new to passing data between VCs so I have no idea how to go about handling this scenario.

**EDIT**
Same error after update
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Achieve it like this.. without Delegate ... write `setIntro` method in `IntroPageController` i hope it will solve your Issue

```
class NewTabBarController: UITabBarController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

    }
}
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                          shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{

        if let controller = viewController as? IntroPageController {

            controller.setIntro(thisFlow: tabBarController.tabBarItem)
        }
        return true
    }
```

You can also achieve it through Protocol for that write... All controllers who confirm `PlanTypeDelegate` can perform action against this method

```
 func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,
                          shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{

        if let navController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            if let myViewController  = navController.topViewController , let homeController = myViewController as? PlanTypeDelegate {
                homeController.setIntro(thisFlow: tabBarController.tabBarItem)
            }
        } else if let controller = viewController as? PlanTypeDelegate {

            controller.setIntro(thisFlow: tabBarController.tabBarItem)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, however the first method did not work. For the 2nd method, how do I set the delegate in the IntroPageController class?

Comment: Should it be tabbar.planTypeDelegate = self ?

Comment: well First one should work ... please confirm IntroPageController has navigationController ?

Comment: No, it does not because it is UIPageViewController subclass.

Comment: check the second method ... you dont need to write delegate .... test it ... it will definitely work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213126/discussion-between-jawadali-and-bvb09).